# Getting a solc error: uint176 - Identifier not found or not unique

Tags: solidity, solc

I'm working on an "Infosphere" contract, an arbitrary key/value store any individual or contract can use.

You can take a look at it here: https://github.com/SafeMarket/dapp/blob/3893cdb499cafae3581bf0ff814c1a80b6640297/app/contracts/Infosphere.sol#L963-L974

I'm getting an error when I try to compile with node solc.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the compiler. Issue created: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/368

Thanks for reporting!